# Speed - CSV vs MariaDB fetching stock data (python)

Tags: python, database, dataset, stock-data

I like the idea of having my historical stock data stored in a database instead of CSV. Is there a speed penalty for fetching large data sets from MariaDB compared to CSV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite the opposite. Whenever you fetch data from a CSV, unless you have a stopping condition (for example, take the first entry with `x = 3`) you must parse **every single line** in the file. This is an expensive operation because not only do you have to read all of the lines (making it `O(n)`), but in general, you will be typecasting as well. In a database, you have already processed all of the lines, and if in this case there is an index on `x` or whatever attribute you are searching by, the database will be able to find the information in `O(log(n))` time and will not look at the vast majority of entries.